Geometries of Two-Player Zero-Sum Games
In a two-player zero-sum game in which each player has one set of two possible actions and mixing is not available, the payoff of Player A as a function of the action each player selects can be visualized as the discrete surface above/below the payoff matrix; that is, each payoff in the matrix is the height of the surface.
If mixing is available, then this surface is continuous (called the Lagrangian) and given by $\vec x^T A \vec y$, where $A$ is the payoff matrix, $\vec x$ is Player A's mix $\begin{bmatrix}\Pr(Top) \\ 1 - \Pr(Top)\end{bmatrix}$, and $\vec y$ is Player B's mix $\begin{bmatrix}\Pr(Left) \\ 1 - \Pr(Left)\end{bmatrix}$.  Here it must also be noted that we only consider the surface over the domain of the unit square, since the input dimensions are probabilities.
In either case, if the game is simultaneous, then the Nash Equilibrium is found by the players instantaneously moving to a saddle point (either intrinsic to the surface or induced by the domain boundary).  If the game is sequential with Player A moving first, then Player A chooses a slice of the surface (a row if it is discrete) and hands it to Player B, who then chooses an outcome from the slice.  So a player's turn in the sequential game seems to be a dimension reduction of the Lagrangian surface by way of a free choice.
How does this generalize to games in which each player has one set of more than two possible actions, and to games in which each player has more than one set of sequential actions (a typical backward induction tree scenario)?  An intuitive geometry would be the game as a higher-dimensional hypersurface gradually dimension reduced by successive free choice as the players progress turns, but I'm not sure this actually describes a generalization correctly.
Finally, this geometry doesn't quite satisfy a hope we might have for it; finding a saddle point feels like a hill climbing algorithm, albeit with Player A climbing up and Player B climbing down.  If we normalize the game's payoffs to lie between $0$ and $1$, then we might interpret them as the probabilities that Player A "wins" the game (after the backward induction tree is traversed, there is a coin flip weighted by the payoff).  Then we would hope for a geometry to express who is winning and by how much as the players progress turns based on the current height on the (high dimensional) hill.  Is a geometry like this related to the dimension reduction geometry in any way?
